# Sending excel data to Tally

Tags: excel, xml, vba, automation, tally

I have a macro enabled worksheet which saves the data as XML format.
I have prepared the excel template which saves the out put file in XML format. Then i import the XML file in Tally manually with import data option.
Now i am looking for a solution which would make the process automatic i.e. once i save the file as XML format, immediately the data should get imported in Tally without any manual process.
Hope i explained my query properly.
Thanks in Advance.
Best Regards,

Comment: Any issues? Is there any further help you require on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Requests to send the xml to tally. Here's a C# example, you can translate it to your preferred language -

```
private static string Connect(string host, string request)
{
    string response = "";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)request.Length;
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(request);
    writer.Close();
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    httpResponse.Close();
}
```

Where host is your tally server ip - usually http://localhost:9000/ and request is your xml - load your xml file as a string.

Ensure your ODBC Server is enabled on Tally. Set your Tally to act as both server and client & choose your port - https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/Tally.ERP9/sync/configuring_client_server.htm

You'll get a response from tally which will have either of the following XML tags -

```
<CREATED>1</CREATED>
or
<ERROR> // some error </ERROR>
```

Tally Intergration documentation isn't great but it can still give you an idea - http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/tally/td9/Tally.ERP9_Integration_Capabilities.pdf

**Lastly,** for automatic upload to tally when the file is created - you can use FileSystemWatcher (C#) or Watchdog library to watch for when the file is created/modified within your specified folder. There is plenty of help in regards to this on stackoverflow.